# How to force to call a couple of functions in sequence?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a class with two functions foo1 and foo2 that must be called in sequence: foo1, foo2.

How to force the user to call foo2 every time he has already called foo1?

Is it possible to check this sequence at compile time?

The background is this: I'm developing a log system based on streams, just like cout, cerr, and so on:

```
trace << "This is a log text followed by a number " << 5 << endl;
```

What I need is to force the user to call *endl* every time he has called *trace*. *endl* must be called before another call to *trace*.

Why?

- When the user calls *endl* the log system must flush. Every message must be flushed as soon as possible.
- The log is also synchronized in order to avoid overlapping of messages. So I lock a mutex in the *trace* call and I unlock it in the *endl* call.

These are the limitations I have:

- It must be as easy as possible, just like cout
- I'm working with Visual Studio 2010, so I can't use c++11.
- I can't use boost libraries because I'm working in a real time environment and my boss wants to avoid it.
- I am in a real time environment (RTX) and we don't want to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: What is the reason behind not having only foo() in the interface which calls foo1() and foo2()?

Comment: Why not make `foo1` and `foo2` private, so the user can't call them manually, then add a public function `foo` that calls both?

Comment: Did you have a look to "Facade" design pattern?

Comment: What is the use case for this? What do `foo1` and `foo2` do? For example, if they are allocation / deallocation functions, there are [patterns for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Answers may vary depending on the nature of the work in `foo1` and `foo2`. You may also be able to get some static analysis tool to perform this check on the source code, in a similar way to the checks for paired `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo_caller {

    template<class OtherStuff>
    void call_foos(OtherStuff&& other_stuff)
    {
        foo1();
        other_stuff();
        foo2();
    }

private:
    void foo1()
    {
        std::cout << "foo1" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo2()
    {
        std::cout << "foo2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo_caller bar;

    bar.call_foos([] {
        std::cout << "here is some other stuff" << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
foo1
here is some other stuff
foo2
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to force the user to call foo2 every time he has already called
>   foo1? Is it possible to check this sequence at compile time?

I like your question!

With 10 minutes or so of thought, I believe the answer is NO.

And I used to proclaim that software is 'infinitely' flexible.  I was wrong.

Here, you have asked the compiler or the code to read another contributors mind.  I think it can not be done.

I think it might be possible for foo2() to confirm that foo1() has been previously called within the last small time measure (microseconds? milliseconds?) by simply capturing the time of invocation.  But that is not guaranteed (interrupt processing can delay 10's of milliseconds, ethernet can be challenging) and not what you asked for.

Looking forward to other answers!  May they prove me wrong, once again.

---

(update)

Perhaps knowing the error has occurred late is better than not knowing at all.

Consider adding a counter for each function, incremented upon each invocation.

Perhaps foo2() can assert() that foo1() has been called no more than once more often?

But will this work if users are allowed to call foo2() without calling foo1()?  Hmmm.  Maybe foo2() must clear both counters?

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the question too much, because imho it should be improved by stating what is the background (i.e. why do you need this?). However, I got inspired by DOUGLAS O. MOENs answer and just for the sake of the OP telling me what is wrong with this approach I would suggest this:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        bool foo1Called;
    public:
        Foo() : foo1Called(false) {}
        void foo1(){
            assert(!foo1Called && "You have to call foo1();foo2();");
            /*...*/
            foo1Called = true;
        }
        void foo2(){
            assert(foo1Called && "You have to call foo1();foo2();");
            /*...*/
            foo1Called = false;
        }
}
```

This is possible, but still I would strongly advise you not to do it but to change the interface (as suggested in comments: provide a public `foo` that calls private `foo1` and `foo2` in the correct order. Actually the purpose of encapsulation is just this).

PS: I just realized that I missed the point, that you want the check at compile time. I would guess it is possible by using some weird tricks, but then again the question arises, why would you need this? Providing the correct interface from the start would fix your problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your edit I would suggest another solution that does not require your clients to call `endl`.

Instead of calling

```
trace << stuff << endl;
```

call

```
Trace() << stuff;
```

The difference is that `Trace()` is actually a constructor call that returns an object inheriting from `std::ostringstream` that you can shift into. This output buffer object calls `endl` and/or prints it or whatever in the destructor. (Note that we don't necessarily print out our debug logs.)

You might not like the parenthesis, but this gives you another opportunity: With the right constructor, you could also write:

```
Trace("The %s is %d!", "foobar", foobar);
```

Or mix them:

```
Trace("The %s is 0x%x", some_string, some_value) << " and then " << some;
```

This is actually what we use for our logging.

Comment: Great!!! *Trace() << stuff;* solve my problem. I don't want the solution *Trace("The %s...."* because the sprintf style is exaclty what we want to avoid, since if the number of % and the arguments don't agree or if the type of an argument is incorrect then Trace fails (BSOD in our RTX case and we can't always test that part of code because it runs on real big machines). But I like the new possibility to mix styles!